# Second degree inequality with one little catch...

Tags: inequality

I need to solve the following inequality for $x$ ($c$ and $u$ are constants):

$$
\frac{x+c\sqrt{x}}{2x+c\sqrt{x+c^2}+c^2}\leq u
$$

where $x\in\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$, $c\in\mathbb{R}^{\gt 1}$, and $u\in\mathbb{R}^{\gt 0.5}$. If we express the inequality in a more canonical form:

$$
0\leq x(2u-1)+uc\sqrt{x+c^2}-uc\sqrt{x}+uc^2
$$

It looks almost like a second degree equation (just solve for $\sqrt{x}$), but I don't know how to get rid of $\sqrt{x+c^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value that function can take is 0.541477, so for $u\gt 0.541477$, $x\geq 0$, otherwise... it's hard to believe how even a very simple square root of a sum can make everything so messy. I better find a reasonable approximation or find more useful restrictions to my problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]